# JavaScript Event Terminology

Tags: javascript, events

What's the difference between an event handler and an event listener?

Up until recently I considered them to be different names for the same thing: a function that's called when an event occurs. But I read something recently that referred to the event handler as the DOM element to which the event listener was bound, which would make sense.

Comment: read this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929528/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-event-handlers-listener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to be perfectly clear, the language itself does not have the concept of events. These are part of the DOM.

```
Event Handler:
    An asynchronous callback that is invoked when an event is raised.
Event Listener: 
    An object that implements an interface and has events "pushed" to it.
```

In the context of DOM events the interface used is this:

```
interface EventListener {
  void handleEvent(in Event evt);
};
```

Then you register a listener like this:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
```

Here is the documentation from [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/addEventListener):

```
listener:
The object that receives a notification when an event of the specified 
type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, 
or simply a JavaScript function.
```

So it looks like function objects implicitly implement **EventListener** for ease of use.

**Analogies**

Think of *Event Handler* as giving the mailman instructions.

> I don't want to have to wait for you
>   to stop by so I want you to give the package to my spouse
>   so they can open it.

Think of *Event Listener* as waiting to see your doctor.

> I will be listening for a notification that you are ready to see me. Until then I'll be reading a magazine.

At the end of the day though these are simply abstractions for

> Hey, I want you to execute this code!

**Resources**

[Event Handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_handler)

[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: @ChaosPandion - Doesn't really help me there as you're using a Java code example and my question was in relation to JavaScript terminology but thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @Nick - This is for JavaScript. The DOM documentation simply describes the interface in generic terms.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - Doh! I'm a bit thick so you'll have to forgive me.

Comment: Why would an "event handler" be asynchronous?

Comment: Good point about being able to pass an object containing a `handleEvent` method into `addEventListener`: I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: @Nick - No Problem. @Tim - It is kind of like giving out your phone number. `I don't want to have to wait around for this to occur so when it does simply call me.`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm aware of what asynchronous means. My question was why you made that distinction on the term "Event Handler" and not "Event Listener".

Comment: @ChaosPandion - So all function objects implement the EventListener interface? I didn't even know there was such a thing in JavaScript. I still don't know what you mean by 'Event Handler: An asynchronous callback that is invoked when an event is raised'. Could you possibly explain that in layman's terms. I understand now that an event listener is any object which implements the EventListener interface.

Comment: Nick: no, function objects don't implement the `EventListener` interface, in the sense that they don't have a `handleEvent` method (actually, JavaScript doesn't have formal interfaces). The key is that the `addEventListener` method of DOM Nodes accepts either a function object or an object with a `handleEvent` method.

Comment: @Tim and Chaos - Thanks guys. It's slowly making sense.

Comment: @Nick - No problem, eventually it will just click, but until then you simply have to get plenty of rest and run a few experiments to see how everything works.

Comment: Chaos: "So it looks like function objects implicitly implement EventListener for ease of use." - where do you get that from? The ECMAScript binding section of the DOM Events spec specifies that the `listener` parameter should simply be a function object. From http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html: *"Object EventListener. This is an ECMAScript function reference. This method has no return value. The parameter is a Event object."* The fact that `someElement.addEventListener("click", { handleEvent: function() { alert("Click"); } }, false);` works could be non-standard.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on the distinction you're making between an event handler and an event listener. The mailbox analogy is odd: you can ignore mail in your mailbox for as long as you like, whereas an event handler/listener is immediately called into action when the event occurs. The mailbox analogy seems more akin to a polling-based system to me: the mailman puts mail in the mailbox, while you go and have a look every now and then to check for new mail.

Comment: @Tim: I agree that it is non-standard but at some point the engineers working on DOM events for Firefox said *"Hey, do we really want people to have to define objects to the interface every single time?"*. So instead they probably did something like this: `if (typeof obj === "function") obj = { handleEvent: obj };`

Comment: @Tim - Hmm, I wonder if *"Asking your spouse to wait for the mail and check for the rebate check."* is more appropriate.

Comment: That's just faster polling  :)

Comment: Event handlers are not asynchronous, though. o_O

Answer (score 3):

In the context of JavaScript, I tend to use them interchangeably. I think the majority of JavaScript developers would consider them to mean the same thing: a function that is called when a particular event occurs. I and I think others would be confused if you referred to the event's target DOM node as the "event handler".

**EDIT**

"Event listener" has a particular meaning within the [DOM Level 2 Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html). The `listener` parameter of the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` methods of event targets (such as elements) is of type `EventListener`, which is specified as an interface containing a single `handleEvent` method. However, JavaScript having no concept of interfaces, in the [ECMAScript Binding section](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html), it specifies:

> **Object EventListener**
>   This is an ECMAScript function reference. This method has no return value. The parameter is a Event object.

So in JavaScript, it seems clear an event listener is a function that is called when an event occurs.

"Event handlers" are also mentioned in the [Scripts section of the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html), which is alluded to in the [DOM Level 2 Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration-html40) (emphasis mine):

> **1.3.2. Interaction with HTML 4.0 event listeners**
>   ...
>   In order to achieve compatibility with HTML 4.0, implementors may view the setting of attributes which represent **event handlers** as the creation and registration of an EventListener on the EventTarget.

It seems clear from this that the two terms mean essentially the same thing in the JavaScript world.

Comment: I have always used them interchangeably but I reading an article on event delegation where a table was capturing all click events that occurred on it and they referred to the table as the handler, which then called the event listener.

Comment: OK. I think it's an unusual use. Have you got a URL for that article?

Comment: No. I know it's not very helpful but I can't find where i read it as it was a while back. I makes in a TODO list of which one was to ask this question.

Comment: What the spec is saying is that attributes such as `onload="func();"`, which is executable code that will be invoked for the `onload` event occurs, is equivalent to `document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("onload", { handleEvent: function(evt) { func(); } }, false);`

Comment: OK, that bit of the spec does seem to be talking about attributes in particular, so perhaps that doesn't really clarify much about event handlers. An `EventListener` is still specified as being just a function object in ECMAScript though, not an object with a `handleEvent` method.