# javascript select input event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a select input from javascript and bind a function to when a user changes an option. So far I have:

```
filter.change = function() {
    console.log("CHANGED");
}
```

But nothing happens on selecting something else. What is wrong with this code. Also, how can I get the new selected value in the function ? Something like:

```
console.log(this.value + "has been selected")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close, you need to use [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange):

```
filter.onchange = function() {
    alert("CHANGED");
    //You can alert the value of the selected option, using this:
    alert(this.value + " was selected");
}
```

Of course as Delan said, you should `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent`) whenever possible. Example:

```
//Define a onchange handler:
var changeHandler = function() {
    alert("CHANGED");
    //You can alert the value of the selected option, using this:
    alert(this.value + " was selected");
}
//First try using addEventListener, the standard method to add a event listener:
if(filter.addEventListener)
  filter.addEventListener("change", changeHandler, false);
//If it doesn't exist, try attachEvent, the IE way:
else if(filter.attachEvent)
  filter.attachEvent("onchange", changeHandler);
//Just use onchange if neither exist
else
  filter.onchange = changeHandler;
```

Comment: Of course, one should use `addEventListener` where available.

Comment: Does addEventListener work in IE?  Can you explain please why addEventListener is better if it has less browser support?

Answer (score 5):

If you use this way, the property name is `onchange`:

```
filter.onchange = function() {
     alert(this.value + "has been selected");
};
```

**Further information:**

- [MDN - HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement)
- [quirksmode.org - Traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

**Note:** There is also another way to register event handlers, which allows to assign multiple event handlers for the same event. For more information, have a look at [*quirksmode.org - Advanced event registration models*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Comment: Of course, one should use `addEventListener` where available.

Comment: Why use addEventListener? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929528/javascript-difference-event-handlers-listener

Comment: @Delan: I would say it depends. If you create a library for sure. If you use it for your own site and don't use any other libraries, this way is easier with respect to all the browser differences.

Comment: Well, the most significant benefit of moving away from the traditional event model is being able to easily add and manage multiple function listeners on an object's event.

Comment: @Delan: Yes, but this comes with the added complexity of handling the differences between W3C and IE. In a simple setup you just don't need this. But I will make a remark...

Answer (score 2):

if you would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can use it like this

```
$('select').change(function(){
   alert($('select').val() + ' was just selected');
});
```

or use .onchange

```
filter.onchange = function() {
    alert(this.value + " was selected");
}
```

instead of  `.change`