# How would I dynamically create input boxes on the fly?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick, drop-down-menu

I want to use the value of a HTML dropdown box and create that number of input boxes underneath. I'm hoping I can achieve this on the fly. Also if the value changes it should add or remove appropriately.

What programming language would I need to do this in? I'm using PHP for the overall website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that uses jQuery to achieve your goals:

Assume you have following html:

```
  <div>
    <select id="input_count">
      <option value="1">1 input</option>
      <option value="2">2 inputs</option>
      <option value="3">3 inputs</option>
    </select>
  <div>
  <div id="inputs"> </div>
```

And this is the js code for your task:

```
  $('#input_count').change(function() {
      var selectObj = $(this);
      var selectedOption = selectObj.find(":selected");
      var selectedValue = selectedOption.val();

      var targetDiv = $("#inputs");
      targetDiv.html("");
      for(var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
        targetDiv.append($("<input />"));
      }
  });
```

You can simplify this code as follows:

```
  $('#input_count').change(function() {
      var selectedValue = $(this).val();

      var targetDiv = $("#inputs").html("");
      for(var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
        targetDiv.append($("<input />"));
      }
  });
```

Here is a working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/melih/VnRBm/

You can read more about jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Simply doing `$(this).val()` on the dropdown gets the selected value, not need to `.find(':selected')`.

Comment: @DidierG. Yes but I had an error when I did it like that, I guess there was some other issue. Now I tried and it works. I'll update the simplified answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Would it be at all possible to keep the values in the box when you change the selected amount. For example, If I had 4 selected then filled out boxes 1 + 2 and then changed it to the selection to 2 and the the data stayed in the 1 and 2 boxes?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for jQuery.

To start with look at change(), empty() and append()

http://api.jquery.com/change/

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in javascript is quite easy. Assuming you've got a number and an html element where to insert. You can obtain the  parent html element by using `document.getElementById` or other similar methods. The method assumes the only children of the `parentElement` is going to be these input boxes. Here's some sample code:

```
function addInput = function( number, parentElement ) {
    // clear all previous children
    parentElement.innerHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        inputEl['type'] = 'text';
        // set other styles here
        parentElement.appendChild(inputEl);
    }
}
```

for the select change event, look here: [javascript select input event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038282/javascript-select-input-event)

Comment: What about the select change event handling?

Answer (score 0):

you would most likely use javascript(which is what jquery is), here is an example to show you how it can be done to get you on your way

```
 <select name="s" onchange="addTxtInputs(this)" onkeyup="addTxtInputs(this)">
 <option value="0">Add</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 </select>
 <div id="inputPlaceHolder"></div>
```

javascript to dynamically create a selected number of inputs on the fly, based on `Mutahhir` answer

```
<script>
function addTxtInputs(o){

  var n = o.value; // holds the value from the selected option (dropdown)
  var p = document.getElementById("inputPlaceHolder"); // this is to get the placeholder element
  p.innerHTML = ""; // clears the contents of the place holder each time the select option is chosen.

// loop to create the number of inputs based apon `n`(selected value) 
   for (var i=0; i < n; i++) { 
       var odiv = document.createElement("div"); //create a div so each input can have there own line
       var inpt = document.createElement("input");
       inpt['type'] = "text"; // the input type is text
       inpt['id'] = "someInputId_" + i; // set a id for optional reference 
       inpt['name'] = "someInputName_" + i; // an unique name for each of the inputs

       odiv.appendChild(inpt); // append the each input to a div
       p.appendChild(odiv); // append the div and inputs to the placeholder (inputPlaceHolder)
     }
 }
</script>
```