# jQuery: create multiple input fields on the basis of how many we select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to create `input` fields on the basis of which number was chosen from `select` menu,
like this code:

```
<select id="inputs" style="width:60px;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>                      
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

When we select 10, `input` fields will increase to 10 at the same time, When I select 2, it doesn't decrease from 10 to 2 :(

I think the best way might be to use `replace()` with a loop; unfotunately I couldn't get a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 0;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1;

    $('#inputs').change(function() {
        var inputFields = parseInt($('#inputs').val());
        for (var n = i; n < inputFields; ++ n){
            wordscount++;
            $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt" href="#">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
        }  
        return false;
    });

    //    Remove button
    $('#add_words').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

​
Could you help me please?

Comment: "I used to try with appendto which doesn't work :(" If you just want to create a new input field then that ought to work. Please show us what you have tried and give us details of exactly why it didn't work, what errors and behaviour you see, etc. You could also just create ten input fields on the page and show / hide them as appropriate, although they will then get submitted with the form which you might not want.

Comment: @Rup I can show you my JQuery code.

Comment: have you refer the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280426/how-would-i-dynamically-create-input-boxes-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make you `DIV` before use append
just try this html

```
<select id="inputs" style="width:60px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>                      
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<div id="add_words"></div>
```

and Jquery with this importand line `scntDiv.empty();`

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1;

    $('#inputs').change(function() {
        var inputFields = parseInt($('#inputs').val());
          scntDiv.empty()
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields; i++){
            scntDiv.append($('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" value="' + wordscount + '" />'));
          }
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputs').change(function(){
        for(i=0; i < $("select option:selected").text; i++)
        {
            $('#divIdHere').append('<input blah blah />');
        }
    })
});
```

obviously change to suit :)

Comment: increase number of fields working fine :). unfortunately decrease doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I realise that you already accepted an answer for this question, but I wasn't content to just leave the question as-is. Also: I was a little bored. Make of that what you will...

So! Here's my (belated) answer.

The benefits of my approach, or the reasoning behind it, are:

1. You can use the `select` to remove, and add, rows.
2. When removing rows using the `select` to remove rows it first removes those lines with empty `input`s, and then removes whatever number of filled in `input`-containing rows from the end.
3. It allows you to use the `.remScnt` links as well.

Hopefully this is of some, even if only academic, use or interest to you:

```
function makeRow() {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        input = document.createElement('input'),
        a = document.createElement('a');
        t = document.createTextNode('remove');
    div.className = 'line';
    input.type = 'text';
    a.href = '#';
    a.className = 'remScnt';
    a.appendChild(t);
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.insertBefore(a, input.nextSibling);

    return div;
}


$('#inputs').change(

function() {
    var num = $(this).val(),
        cur = $('div.line input:text'),
        curL = cur.length;
    if (!curL) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

            $(makeRow()).appendTo($('body'));
        }
    }
    else if (num < curL) {
        var filled = cur.filter(

        function() {
            return $(this).val().length
        }),
            empties = curL - filled.length,
            dA = curL - num;

        if (empties >= num) {
            cur.filter(

            function() {
                return !$(this).val().length;
            }).parent().slice(-num).remove();
        }
        else if (empties < num) {
            var remainder = num - empties;
            cur.filter(

            function() {
                return !$(this).val().length;
            }).parent().slice(-num).remove();
            $('div.line').slice(-remainder).remove();
        }
    }
    else {
        var diff = num - curL;
        for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            $(makeRow()).appendTo($('body'));
        }
    }
});
$('body').on('click', '.line a.remScnt', function() {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).parent().remove();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bFW2G/1/).

Please note that I've made little, or (more precisely) no, attempt to ensure cross-browser usability with this. The native DOM methods used in the `makeRow()` function are used for (minor optimisations of increasing the) speed, using jQuery (with its cross-browser-abstractions might make things even more reliable. And is worth considering.

References:

1. Native vanilla JavaScript:

   - [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
   - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
   - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode).
   - [`element.className()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className).
   - [`node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore).
2. jQuery stuff:

   - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
   - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
   - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
   - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
   - [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).
   - [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
   - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

okay change it a little to allow for a new list to be created.

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputs').change(function(){
        $('#divIdHere').empty()
        for(i=0; i < $("select option:selected").text; i++)
        {
            $('#divIdHere').append('<input blah blah />');
        }
    })
});
```

that will basically empty out the contents of the div before adding them all back in again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could only add new lines to make up the number of lines when the select's value increases and only remove the 'extra' lines when it decreases.

```
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
        var divs = $( 'div#add_words' );
        $( '#inputs' ).change(
            function(evt) {
                var n = $( this ).val();
                var lines = $( 'div.line' );
                var numlines = lines.size();
                if( n > numlines ) {
                    // We want more line. Add some.
                    while( n > numlines ) {
                        numlines += 1;
                        divs.append( '<div class="line">Line ' + numlines + '</div>' );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Remove everything after the n'th line.
                    lines.slice( n ).remove();
                }
            } )
        .change();
    } );
```