# Symfony2 Handler vs Listener what the difference?

Tags: symfony

I need to create **listener or handler** to provide some actions for **AccessDenied exception**.

I've looked some sources of standard handlers and listeners, so looks like they can be use for same task.

I also read this:

1. [What's the difference between Event Listeners & Handlers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725241/whats-the-difference-between-event-listeners-handlers-in-java)
2. [JavaScript - What's the difference between event handlers & listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929528/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-event-handlers-listener)
3. [Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface)

But only difference I've seen - that handlers often use for handle exceptions.

**So, what the real difference between handler and listener in Symfony ?**

Comment: What is the "symfony2 handler" at the very first place?

Comment: @zerkms I don't understand the question, can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: Where did you get that term from? What do you exactly mean when you say "symfony2 handler"?

Comment: I see that, but how did you come to the "handler" term?

Comment: @zerkms For example, standard SecurityBundle contains different handlers, handlers and listeners registered at the same file as services, and as I can understand, I can use handler or listener for the same task

Comment: @zerkms I have answered your question ?

Comment: So check the `SecurityBundle` documentation. It's a bundle-specific thing, not something generic to the symfony2 in general.

Comment: @zerkms handlers not only used in SecurityBundle. In other bundles too

Comment: And? It's still a bundle specific thing - a bundle can declare: "this thing is called a handler and it does this job". There is no single framework-wide definition for the term and requirements on what it must do. You, as a bundle author are free to call literally any thing "a handler", just because you can.

Comment: @zerkms ok, your comment looks useful, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Listeners` are registered and called when an event occurs. [Observer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) or [PubSub](https://mwop.net/blog/199-A-Simple-PHP-Publish-Subscribe-System.html) patterns are used.

The `Handler` is more of a [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/php) that delegates implementation details to class. Which can then be substituted. (composition over inheritance)

The patterns could maybe be interchangeable in some cases, and it's more the intention of the code that calls for one or the other then.

Comment: Important: symfony2 declares the `listener` entity as a part of its Event Dispatcher, but the `handler` term is not officially defined by the framework. So it's not guaranteed that what you stated about the `handler` is true for everything.

Comment: After reading your answer, I still don't understand anything :))